# Surface integral ( limits of surface)

Tags: surface-integrals

Calculate
$$\iint_{S} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{1+2x^{2}}} dS$$
where
$$S =\{(x, y, x^{2}+y ) , 0 \leq x \leq y, x+y \leq 1\} $$

My attempt is this [image: my attempt]

i cannot figure out the limits of $x$ and $y$

In the ans it is given  $ 0<y<1$ and  $-y< x< 1-y$
While i think it should be $ 0<x<1/2$ and $x<y<1-x$

Comment: You’re right. To do $y$ as the outside integral will require two separate integrals. As always, a picture is mandatory.

Comment: Your limits are correct.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I didn't really look to closely at your picture, as it was quite messy, so if this is what you did then you got it right.

Notice that $S$ is the graph of the function

$$f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R},\quad (x,y)\mapsto x^2+y,$$

where

$$\Omega=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 :  0\leq x\leq y\land x+y\leq 1\}.$$

Notice also that

$$\nabla f(x,y)=(2x,1),$$

from which we have that

$$\lVert \nabla f(x,y)\rVert^2=4x^2+1.$$

We then have that

$$I=\iint_S\frac{xy}{\sqrt{1+2x^2}}~\mathrm{d}S=\iint_\Omega \frac{xy}{\sqrt{1+2x^2}}\sqrt{1+4x^2+1}~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y=\iint_\Omega xy\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+2x^2}}{\sqrt{1+2x^2}}~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y=\sqrt{2}\iint_\Omega xy~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y.$$

Now let's turn this into an iterated integral. Let's take $x$ as our outer integration variable, and so we can let $y$ depend on $x$ (the other way can also be done, but it gets more messy, and will lead to having to split it into two integrals). Notice that we can rewrite

$$x+y\leq 1$$

as

$$y\leq 1-x.$$

Combining this with the inequality

$$0\leq x\leq y$$

gives us then that $\Omega$ can be expressed as

$$\Omega=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : 0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2} \land x\leq y\leq 1-x\right\}$$

($x\leq\frac{1}{2}$ as $x> x-1$ otherwise). This finally means that

$$I=\sqrt{2}\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\int_x^{1-x}xy~\mathrm{d}y~\mathrm{d}x.$$

At this point it's just a standard computation so I'll leave the details to you.